# oci_bind_by_name(): Unknown or unsupported datatype given: 156

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am having issues trying to call a procedure.  I am using PHP7.  One of my OUTs is an Oracle Timestamp. Running my code through PHP I get

```
oci_bind_by_name(): Unknown or unsupported datatype given: 156
```

Here is my code:

```
$connection = $this->createConnection();
$stid = oci_parse($connection, "begin add_item(:name, :time_created, :id); end;");
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":name", $name, 128, SQLT_CHR);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":time_created", $timeCreated, -1, SQLT_ODT);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":id", $id, -1, SQLT_INT);
oci_execute($stid);
```

My procedure:

```
create or replace procedure add_item (
    p_item in varchar2,
    p_time_ticket_created out timestamp,
    p_id out number)
as
begin
...
```

The enum for SQLT_ODT is 156.  Is SQLT_ODT really not supported in oci_bind_by_name?

Comment: From the PHP Manual for oci_bind_name() http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php the SQLT_ODT is not used in oci_bind_by_name but in oci_bind_array_by_name()  http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-array-by-name.php

Comment: Ok then. I suppose I'm asking for a way to implement retrieving SQLT_ODT types using oci_bind_array_by_name() as I cannot find any examples.

Comment: Here is a good example of what you would like to do : http://www.navioo.com/php/tutorials/Array_Binding_and_PLSQL_Bulk_Processing_863.html

Comment: Thank you Marc, that did help me out.

Comment: Glad it helps !